# any SQL standard where you don't have to SELECT the column you GROUP BY with in order to see it?

Tags: sql

```
select count(viewer)
from table
group by movie_title
```

Is there any SQL variant where you see the movie_title in the result to a query like this?
I have to grade some tests sometimes, and I see these soooo many times, I am actually curious.

In short, will any SQL variant give back the same results as below?

```
select movie_title,
       count(viewer)
from table
group by movie_title
```

Comment: Try it, you will see the result.

Comment: You have to select the movie_title column to have it returned.

Comment: It's difficult to prove that *no* SQL dialect would behave that way but it would be highly surprising and I can't think of any *common* SQL dialect where it would happen.

Comment: If any database did return the movie_title in the first query this would be a major violation of the SQL standard and its rules. A will **only** return the columns (or expressions) listed in the SELECT list. If that was the answer to a test question I would probably mark it as wrong assuming the question was "*show the title of each movie and the number of viewers*" - or something along the lines.

Answer (score 0):

ok thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I just wanted to be sure.
"If any database did return the movie_title in the first query this would be a major violation of the SQL standard and its rules. A will only return the columns (or expressions) listed in the SELECT list. If that was the answer to a test question I would probably mark it as wrong assuming the question was "show the title of each movie and the number of viewers" - or something along the lines."